# Google Apps Script - calendar shift generator - can we split dates and times?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps-script

Ok so I jumped in at the deep end a bit with Google Apps Script. At work we have week long shifts of set hours. The three types of shifts can be Earlies (7am - 3.30pm), Middles (8.30am to 5pm) and Lates (10.30am to 7pm).

What I am trying to do is generate a UI with a date picker and 3 buttons, one for each shift. The idea is you click a Monday on the date picker, then click a shift button and it generates 5 shifts (one for each day of the week) and adds them as events to my Google calendar.

I can get the functions to generate the events, but I am unable to tie in the input from the date picker into the date for each function. Is there any way of splitting the date and time for the events? Ideally the time would be 'Hard coded' into the script so it couldn't be changed but the date would be user selectable.

I hope all this makes sense, code below:

```
// loads the UI
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var label1 = app.createLabel("To use this application, select a Monday and then hit the Early Middle or Late button");
   app.add(label1);
  var label2 = app.createLabel("5 events will be created from the start date across five days");
   app.add(label2);

   var picker = app.createDatePicker().setId("picker");
   var handler = app.createServerHandler("change");
    app.add(picker);

  var button1 = app.createButton("Early").setId("button1");
   button1.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("early"));
   app.add(button1);

   var button2 = app.createButton("Middle").setId("button2");
    button2.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("middle"));
   app.add(button2);

  var button3 = app.createButton("Late").setId("button3");
   button3.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("late"));
   app.add(button3);

   return app;
};

//Handles date picker changes
 function change(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.add(app.createLabel("The value of the date picker changed to " +     eventInfo.parameter.picker));
  return app;
};


//Generates the events
 function early(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var title = "Computacenter";
  var start = new Date("July 21, 2012 07:00:00");  
  var end = new Date("July 21, 2012 15:30:00");
  var loc = "Unspecified";
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);

  var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, recurrence, {location : loc});

};


function middle(){

  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var title = "Computacenter";
  var start = new Date("July 21, 2012 08:30:00");
  var end = new Date("July 21, 2012 17:00:00");
  var loc = "Unspecified";
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);

  var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, recurrence, {location : loc});

};


function late(){

  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var title = "Computacenter";
  var start = new Date("July 21, 2012 10:30:00");
  var end = new Date("July 21, 2012 19:00:00");
  var loc = "Unspecified";
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);

  var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, recurrence, {location : loc});

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - there is something known as callback element which you have to add to your sever handler.

So, ideally instead of adding all the UI elements directly, I would create a panel and add to the panel. 
Something like

```
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel'); 
app.add(panel); 
/* .... */
panel.add(picker); 
/* and the like... */

button2.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("middle").addCallbackElement(panel));
```

Using that you should be able to get the date selected in the date picker using eventInfo.parameter.picker

Answer (score 0):

Here is your revised code

```
// loads the UI
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var container = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var label1 = app.createLabel("To use this application, select a Monday and then hit the Early Middle or Late button");
   container.add(label1);
  var label2 = app.createLabel("5 events will be created from the start date across five days");
   container.add(label2);

   var picker = app.createDatePicker().setId("picker");
   var handler = app.createServerHandler("change");
  picker.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
    container.add(picker);

  var button1 = app.createButton("Early").setId("button1");
   button1.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("generateEvents").addCallbackElement(container));
   container.add(button1);

   var button2 = app.createButton("Middle").setId("button2");
    button2.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("generateEvents").addCallbackElement(container));
   container.add(button2);

  var button3 = app.createButton("Late").setId("button3");
   button3.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("generateEvents").addCallbackElement(container));
   container.add(button3);

  app.add(container);

   return app;
};

//Handles date picker changes
 function change(eventInfo) {
   Logger.log(eventInfo);
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.add(app.createLabel("The value of the date picker changed to " +     eventInfo.parameter.picker));
  return app;
};


//Generates the events
 function generateEvents(e){
   var source = e.parameter.source;
   var date = e.parameter.picker.getDate();
   var month = e.parameter.picker.getMonth(); 
   var year = e.parameter.picker.getFullYear();

   var startTime;
   var endTime;

   //(7am - 3.30pm), Middles (8.30am to 5pm) and Lates (10.30am to 7pm).
   if(source == 'button1'){
     var startTime = '07:00';
     var endTime = '15:30';
   }

   //Middle events time
   if(source == 'button2'){
     var startTime = '08:30';
     var endTime = '17:00';
   }

   //Late events time
   if(source == 'button3'){
     var startTime = '10:30';
     var endTime = '19:00';
   }

  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var title = "Computacenter";
   //Using format new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds); 
  var start = new Date(year, month, date, parseInt(startTime.substring(0,2)), parseInt(startTime.subString(3,5)));
  var end = new Date(year, month, date, parseInt(endTime.substring(0,2)), parseInt(endTime.subString(3,5)));
  var loc = "Unspecified";
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);

  var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, recurrence, {location : loc});

};
```

Comment: You sir, are a god! Now I just have iron out one error, 'TypeError: Cannot find function getDate in object'

Comment: @Waqar : it's not subString() but substring() ;-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference either way on mine :( Which is weird because taking out the whole substring bit altogether and using just parseInt works, but rounds the hours for the half hour interval ones, so it definitely seems to be something wrong with the parsing substrings bit, just can't work out what :s

Comment: Thank you Serge for pointing this out. I can not open Docs and Apps Script in my office as these are blocked and can't test. I just wrote those on Notepad++. Will edit those :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the approach you have chosen will not be useable, well at least not very user friendly nor 'fool proof'.(even with the callback element).  You'll find it quite hard to avoid that someone choses a wrong combination.

I'd recommend to use 3 radio buttons or a listBox for hours shifts and a date picker for dates. Hours in the radio buttons would be strings that you could easily translate to start time / end time that you could combine with dates. Also the date picker is not the best solution if you want to work with weeks since one can choose any day in the week and, if I understood you well, the  chosen day should always be monday for the system to work doesn't it ?

I have an [application with almost the same situation](https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbyc2SWv6JhDgUpXwF7aAARihIE7WPRmrQf6KIOtfQ) concerning dates and time slices, You could have a look at it and see how it works, I think it could suit your use case quite well at least in its approach, It gives a choice for every day of the week but this choice could be reduced to one.  The script is [shown here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/reservation-gui) as well. Feel free to ask if you need more details.

**EDIT :** *Waqar's answer came while I was writing, his proposal is not far from mine ;-) and solves almost every issue... just think about replacing the date picker of find a way to reject any 'not monday' choice !*

**EDIT 2 :** to get your correct time and date you can go like this (using Number() to convert strings in numbers):

```
   var date = Number(e.parameter.picker.getDate());
   var month =Number(e.parameter.picker.getMonth()); 
   var year = Number(e.parameter.picker.getFullYear());
...
...
       var st = startTime.split(':');// returns an array of 2 string elements
           var stH=Number(st[0]);
           var stM=Number(st[1]) ;              
       var et = endTime.split(':')
           var etH=Number(et[0]);
           var etM=Number(et[1]) ;              
       //Using format new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds); 
      var start = new Date(year,month,date,stH,stM,0,0);
      var end = new Date(year,month,date,etH,etM,0,0);
       Logger.log(start+'   '+end)
      var loc = "Unspecified";
      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(5);

      var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, recurrence, {location : loc});
```

or also, keeping strings all along :

```
   var startstring = year+','+month+','+date+','+startTime.replace(':',',')+', 00,000'
   var endstring =  year+','+month+','+date+','+endTime.replace(':',',')+', 00,000'
   Logger.log('start = '+startstring+'      end = '+endstring)
   var st = startstring.split(',')
   var et = endstring.split(',')

   var start = new Date(st[0],st[1],st[2],st[3],st[4],st[5],st[6]);
   var end = new Date(et[0],et[1],et[2],et[3],et[4],et[5],et[6]);
   Logger.log(start+'   '+end)
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe some sort of drop down box that displays every Monday for x amount of Mondays in the future, starting from today's date.

Comment: That's exactly what I did :-)   did you try the link?

Comment: Ah I've just noticed the date selector drop down at the top, I only saw the days before, you are many steps ahead of me :)